# ENTER key doesn’t work in “Interesting tags” and “Ignored tags” textfields

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, tag-watching, ignored-tags

The “Interesting Tags” and “Ignored Tags” UI to the right of the list of Newest Questions have a textbox and a button each. It is customary to accept the ENTER key in place of having to click the button with the mouse. Please add the ability to press ENTER in these textboxes.

Comment: I didn't believe you, I had to try it myself. Looks like you're right...  You can still do it without the mouse though, if you tab to the "Add" button and hit enter or spacebar.